# MS SQL Server get no. of months between two dates in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

DATE                       CusID       Count
-------                   -------     -------
31/10/2018 00:00:00      5677          1
06/06/2018 00:00:00      5677          1
04/05/2018 00:00:00      5677          1
02/03/2018 00:00:00      5677          1
04/01/2018 00:00:00      5677          1
02/03/2018 00:00:00      5678          1

Answer required

CusID     Order1         Order2           Order 3           Order 4........so on
5677      04/01/2018     02/03/2018      04/05/2018       06/06/2018
5678      02/03/2018

Comment: what have you researched or tried so far? This is not really a free write-my-code or do-my-thinking service. We like to _help_ you with your code, not just do all of your work for you. What problem are you facing, specifically?

Comment: P.S. Here's a clue though...this may be useful to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL-Server 2012 you use the following solution using [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql):

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.[Date1], t.[Date2]) AS number_of_months
FROM (
  SELECT CusID, [Date] AS [Date1], LEAD([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY CusID ORDER BY CusID, [Date]) AS [Date2]
  FROM table_name
) t WHERE t.[Date1] IS NOT NULL AND t.[Date2] IS NOT NULL
```

On SQL-Server 2008 and earlier you can use the following solution using a `INNER JOIN` and [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
SELECT t1.CusID, t1.[Date] AS [Date1], t2.[Date] AS [Date2], DATEDIFF(MONTH, t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) AS number_of_months FROM (
  SELECT CusID, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CusID ORDER BY [Date]) rn
  FROM table_name
) t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CusID, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CusID ORDER BY [Date]) rn
  FROM table_name
) t2 ON t1.rn + 1 = t2.rn AND t1.CusID = t2.CusID
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1ca3e14cbe089c16d514be7b06bc5133)